# azure after midnight and before 01:00 am has not updated to BST

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure Table which is a datetime field and we use GetDate() to obtain the default, which is todays date and time.

However between the hours of Midnight and 01:00am the GetDate() is not returning the correct date due to British Summer Time. Apart from midnight - 1am the GetDate() returns the correct BST

Answer (score 2):

GetDate() in Azure SQL Database always returns UTC regardless of the database location or user location. I believe that British Summer Time is UTC + 1, so the behavior you are describing is expected.